# gcloud ai-platform hypertuning pass enviroment variable to custom containers

Tags: docker, gcloud

I am running hypertuning using gcloud ai-platform of a model build into an image. 
I need hypertnuning job to load custom container with model training and pass environment variable to it.
In docker i can use -e. Can not find a way to make

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training
```

pass enviroment variables to custom containers.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the Documentation how to do [Hyperparameter Tuning with Containers](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/using-containers#hyperparameter_tuning_with_custom_containers). It includes [an example](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/custom-containers-training#submit_a_hyperparameter_tuning_job) too!

Comment: Thank you, Albert. It is a great resource, but does not tell how to make job dispatcher pass environment variables to containers. gcloud ai-platform help does not help too.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your use case? Can't you pass the variables in the submit using argparse and then make your python script set environment variables using OS?

Comment: This will expose variable in the log, as it is secret, I do not want it to stay in logs.